# Angular 8 Property 'localStorage' does not exist on type 'ApplicationRegisterComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm fairly new to TypeScript and I'm trying to build a translation based app which requires the use of localStorage; however when I try to call it, it returns the error;  `Property 'localStorage' does not exist on type 'ApplicationRegisterComponent'.` to me.

This would be my `application-register-component.ts` code;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application-register',
  templateUrl: './application-register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-register.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  public isViewable: boolean;

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('language')){
      translate.setDefaultLang(localStorage.getItem('language'));
      translate.use(localStorage.getItem('language'));
    }else {
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        translate.use('en');
        localStorage.setItem("language","en");
    }
  }

  useLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isViewable = true;
  }

  toggleen() {
    this.isViewable = !this.isViewable;
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translate.use('en');
  };

  togglecn(){
    this.isViewable = true;
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('cn');
    this.translate.use('cn');
    this.localStorage.setItem("language","cn");
  };

}
```

The error is found here:

```
this.localStorage.setItem("language","cn");
```

Comment: localStorage is not a property of your 'ApplicationRegisterComponent ' class so you cannot use 'this' keyword .
try localStorage.setItem("language","cn");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is not a property of your `ApplicationRegisterComponent` class. So, you cannot use 'this' keyword with it.
Try,

```
localStorage.setItem("language","cn");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing this keyword. Hope it works.

```
localStorage.setItem("language","cn");
```